# Recommendations for Python GUI application

Tags: python

What are your recommendations for GUI libraries for Python.  My own research has me looking at TKinter, but I am open to suggestions.

FYI, the Python application will serve as a kind of bridge between 2 applications.  It will use the third party API to extract data, then move and rename the data into a canonical folder structure, use Robocopy to transfer the exported into our in-house processing environment and make proper entries into our in-house database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/gui.html) for a list of some GUI development platforms.

**Tkinter**

> Standard builds of Python include an object-oriented interface to the Tcl/Tk widget set, called Tkinter. This is probably the easiest to install and use. For more info about Tk, including pointers to the source, see the Tcl/Tk home page at http://www.tcl.tk. Tcl/Tk is fully portable to the Mac OS X, Windows, and Unix platforms.

**wxWidgets**

> wxWidgets (http://www.wxwidgets.org) is a free, portable GUI class library written in C++ that provides a native look and feel on a number of platforms, with Windows, Mac OS X, GTK, X11, all listed as current stable targets. Language bindings are available for a number of languages including Python, Perl, Ruby, etc.
>
> wxPython (http://www.wxpython.org) is the Python binding for wxwidgets. While it often lags slightly behind the official wxWidgets releases, it also offers a number of features via pure Python extensions that are not available in other language bindings. There is an active wxPython user and developer community.
>
> Both wxWidgets and wxPython are free, open source, software with permissive licences that allow their use in commercial products as well as in freeware or shareware.

**Qt**

> There are bindings available for the Qt toolkit (using either PyQt or PySide) and for KDE (PyKDE). PyQt is currently more mature than PySide, but you must buy a PyQt license from Riverbank Computing if you want to write proprietary applications. PySide is free for all applications.
>
> Qt 4.5 upwards is licensed under the LGPL license; also, commercial licenses are available from The Qt Company.

These three are probably the most common ones but you can try others if you wish.

Having only used Tkinter and [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) I would recommend PyQt, however this may not be what you need so I recomend doing some research to find out which will best suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Just googling "GUI libraries for Python" you can get "GUI Programming in Python":

> > https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming
> >
> > Due to this site -- Python has a huge number of GUI frameworks available for it, from TkInter to a number of other cross-platform solutions ... Please, have a look at them ... and find out a suitable tool :)

Comment: `Atlas toolkit for Python` is a good choice!